# How to update iPhone 6/6s from iOS 12.5 to a more recent version?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

I purchased a used iPhone from Amazon. I picked out an iPhone 6 with 64 MB. When I received the phone I opened **Settings** > **General** > **About** it was labeled “iPhone 6”.

Scrolling through the settings I found the Siri app turning it on, it worked. Now in the **Settings** > **About** where my phone was listed as a 6 just below that it lists my iPhone as a 6s.

I had to replace the data, charge flex cable I purchased one for a 6 as well, it didn’t match the one inside the phone. I purchased a 6s this time and it was a match, swapped it out everything worked fine. Now what I’m wondering is if I paid for an iPhone 6 but got an iPhone 6s but it’s labeled as a 6 in the settings stated above and in my paperwork but I cannot get iOS 13 on the phone even though it updated to iOS 12.5 this last time.

As far as all the reading an iPhone 6 cannot be upgraded to a 6s.
I have 54.5 of memory left plenty of space to install iOS 13.

What can I do to get my iPhone to update to the latest iOS software?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. iOS 12 is the last OS that runs on this older hardware.

Comment: If you have iOS 12.5, you don't have an iPhone 6s. Also, you won't be able to install iOS 13 on an iPhone 6s, only iOS 14.